# ENOENT: no such file or directory in react vite

Tags: reactjs, vite, enoent

I have created a project using react and i used github actions also to store some api keys now when i try to "npm run deployed" it is normal at start but after showing this error.

Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat 'C:\Users\heman\OneDrive\Documents\GitHub\Portfolio-Hemanth\build'
at Object.statSync (node:fs:1696:3)
at Object.statSync (C:\Users\heman\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\gh-pages\node_modules\graceful-fs\polyfills.js:319:16)
at Object.publish (C:\Users\heman\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\gh-pages\lib\index.js:90:13)
at C:\Users\heman\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\gh-pages\bin\gh-pages.js:12:13
at new Promise ()
at publish (C:\Users\heman\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\gh-pages\bin\gh-pages.js:10:10)
at C:\Users\heman\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\gh-pages\bin\gh-pages.js:133:12

I asked chatgpt and i browsed over internet and i try everting but it fails
but i don't know why this problem is coming

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.